# Android 10 app notifications not working after an upgrade from only testing android 7

Tags: java, android, notifications

I made an android app in java and it worked on my old device that ran nougat (android 7), I recently got a new phone that runs Android 10, and the entire app works just fine, except for creating a notification.
Why is this happening? and how do I fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Starting in Android 8, all notifications must have a notification channel:

https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels

You should get a stack trace that says exactly this when your app tries and fails to show a notification.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out and I'll let you know if that works